# linux find on multiple patterns

Tags: linux, bash

I need to do a find on roughly 1500 file names and was wondering if there is a way to execute simultaneous find commands at the same time.

Right now I do something like

```
for fil in $(cat my_file)
do
  find . -name $fil >> outputfile
done
```

is there a way to spawn multiple instances of find  to speed up the process. Right now it takes about 7 hours to run this loop one file at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution calls `find` and `fgrep` only once:

```
find . | fgrep -f my_file > outputfile
```

I assume that `my_file` has a list of files you are looking for, with each name on a separate line.

#### Explanation

1. The `find` command finds all the files (including directories) in the current directory. Its output is a list of files/directories, one per line
2. The `fgrep` command search from the output of the find command, but instead of specifying the search term on the command line, it gets the search terms from `my_file`--that's what the `-f` flag for.
3. The output of the fgrep command, which is the list of files you are looking for, are redirected into `outputfile`

Comment: Wow yeah this was what I needed. A little explanation pleasee.

Answer (score 3):

Given the 7-hour runtime you mention, I presume the file system has some millions of files in it so that OS disk buffers loaded in one query are being reused before the next query begins.  You can test this hypothesis by timing the same `find` a few times, as in following example.

```
tini ~ > time find . -name IMG_0772.JPG -ls
25430459 9504 lrwxrwxrwx   1 omg omg  9732338 Aug  1 01:33 ./pix/rainbow/IMG_0772.JPG
20341373 5024 -rwxr-xr-x   1 omg omg  5144339 Apr 22  2009 ./pc/2009-04/IMG_0772.JPG
22678808 2848 -rwxr-xr-x   1 omg omg  2916237 Jul 21 21:03 ./pc/2012-07/IMG_0772.JPG

real    0m15.823s
user    0m0.908s
sys 0m1.608s

tini ~ > time find . -name IMG_0772.JPG -ls
25430459 9504 lrwxrwxrwx   1 omg omg  9732338 Aug  1 01:33 ./pix/rainbow/IMG_0772.JPG
20341373 5024 -rwxr-xr-x   1 omg omg  5144339 Apr 22  2009 ./pc/2009-04/IMG_0772.JPG
22678808 2848 -rwxr-xr-x   1 omg omg  2916237 Jul 21 21:03 ./pc/2012-07/IMG_0772.JPG

real    0m0.715s
user    0m0.340s
sys 0m0.368s
```

In the example, the second `find` ran much faster because the OS still had buffers in RAM from the first  `find`.  [On my small Linux 3.2.0-32 system, according to `top` at the moment 2.5GB of RAM is buffers, 0.3GB is free, and 3.8GB in use (ie about 1.3GB for programs and OS).]

Anyhow, to speed up processing, you need to find a way to make better use of OS disk buffering.   For example, double or quadruple your system memory.  For an alternative, try the `locate` command.  The query
`time locate IMG_0772.JPG`
consistently takes under a second on my system.  You may wish to run `updatedb` just before starting the job that finds the 1500 file names.  See `man updatedb`.  If directory `.` in your `find`'s gives only a small part of the overall file system, so that the `locate` database includes numerous irrelevant files, use various `prune` options when you run `updatedb`, to minimize the size of the `locate` database that is accessed when you run `locate`; and afterwards, run a plain `updatedb` to restore other filenames to the `locate` database.  Using `locate` you probably can cut the run time to 20 minutes.

Comment: Absolutely. If all you need to do is look for files by name, you should use `locate`.

Comment: locate doesn't find any files in our source tree I think it has to do with the fact that our source tree is actually a sort of virtual file system that doesn't exist until a clearcase view is set.

Comment: @mike, perhaps edit the question and say what the  file system  is, the number of files, and if access is via network.  If query is running on a VM different answers may apply

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like

```
find . \( -name file1 -o -name file2 -o ... \) >outputfile
```

You could build lines of this kind, depending on the number of names in `my_file`:

```
find . \( $(xargs <my_file printf "-name %s -o " | sed 's/-o $//') \) >outputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to spawn multiple instances of find to speed up the process.

This is not how you want to solve the problem, since `find` is I/O- and FS-limited.

Either use multiple `-name` arguments grouped together with `-o` in order to use one `find` command to look for multiple filenames at once, or find *all* files once and use a tool such as `grep` to search the resultant list of files for the filenames of interest.